# How to fine-tune match_all queries?

Tags: elasticsearch

The following query yields results:

```
GET /sentinel/pingback/_search
{
      "match_all": {}
}
```

I wanted to fine-tune the `query` to add a time range

```
GET /sentinel/pingback/_search
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "time": {
            "gte": "now-20m"
         }
      },
      "match_all": {}
   }
}
```

This does not work anymore, the error is

```
"error": {
      "root_cause": [
         {
            "type": "parse_exception",
            "reason": "failed to parse search source. expected field name but got [START_OBJECT]"
         }
      ],
(...)
```

The time range, however, correctly works when on its own

```
GET /sentinel/pingback/_search
{
   "query": {
      "range": {
         "time": {
            "gte": "now-20m"
         }
      }
   }
}
```

I was therefore expecting that for one `query` I could add independent "fine-tuning" components (like `range`for instance) but apparently it does not work this way.

**How to combine these query constraints?**

Note: I know that I can get rid of `match_all` in the query above. I want to keep it because it will either be a `match_all` or a `match` (which is another constraint I was wishing to add to the all-encompassing `query`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can combine constraints using the bool query:

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-bool-query.html

But I don't get really the point why you want to combine match_all with match query. For me doesn't really make sense.

EDIT:

If you want to match either every document or filter one field value for a specific value, you should do that in a programming language, like javascript.

Match will just match a value as the name states. If you want to look for exact matches, have a look at the term query (depending on your ES version also term filter for < 2.0).

https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-term-query.html

Then if no filter is selected, just do a match_all, otherwise build together your query json with the term query. If you have multiple constraints, combine them using the bool query.

For several programming languages there are also query builder libraries,
e.g. for javascript (official one):

https://www.npmjs.com/package/elasticsearch

Basically the queries work the same from a logic perspective as in other databases, just the syntax is different.

Comment: The body of the query will be built programatically. In one case i will want to match everything (using `"match_all": {}`) and in other cases there I need to match an exact value of a field (though `match`). Since I did not find a wildcard for matches (to say that the field `name` for instance can be anything), I must (?) use `"match_all": {}` It is true that I have a hard time understanding the logic of the search bodies in ES)

Comment: See my edit. Also only one thing where is makes sense to combine is when you want to search for a specific value and append the remaining not matching documents afterwards in the result. There you can set a score for the matching documents of 3 for example and the remaining ones in the match all get a 1. Score 3 is higher than 1, so they come first.

Comment: Thanks. Thanks to your comment on `bool` I worked out the solution and posted as an answer. Thanks for the head up!

Answer (score 1):

Based on [Nilz11's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38610456/903011), I found out how to approach the problem. The key (as far as I understand) is to gather all the constraints in `bool`.

In my example that would be:

**for `match_all`:**

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "range": {
                  "time": {
                     "gte": "now-10m"
                  }
               }
            },
            {
               "match_all": {}
            }
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

**for the specific match** (a name for instance):

```
{
   "query": {
      "bool": {
         "must": [
            {
               "range": {
                  "time": {
                     "gte": "now-10m"
                  }
               }
            },
            { "match": { "name": "John"}}
         ]
      }
   }
}
```

Comment: In the first case you can leave out match_all, as it will anyway return all results + filtered by the range query.

Comment: Thanks. Yes, I realized that I now ended up with a list (`[...]`) which is easily expandable programatically so I do not need the "matching part" placeholder I needed before.